# Mostrar Datos filtrados de tabla relacionada

Tags: php, laravel-6

Estoy realizando una plataforma de fletes con Laravel 6 y tengo que realizar un filtro en la vista para obtener a los choferes que tengan asignada una ruta, las rutas que muestro en el `select` tienen diferente `id` a las que se asignaron al chofer ya que al asignar la ruta se crea un nuevo registro en la DB. El `select` que muestro  es así:

```
<form action="{{ route('udisponible.index') }}" method="GET">
    <select name="rutasU" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="">RUTAS</option>
        @foreach($rutas as $ruta)
        <option value="{{ $ruta->id }}" {{ ($ruta->id == $rutaU) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $ruta->origen->ciudad }} - {{ $ruta->destino->ciudad }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
```

La consulta y el filtro lo estoy realizando de la siguiente forma

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $users = User::rutas($request->rutasU)
    ->where('tipo_usuario_id',4)
    ->orWhere('tipo_usuario_id',5)
    ->get();
    $rutas = Ruta::where('solicitada_por',Auth::id())->get();
    return view('cliente.unidades-disponibles.index',compact('users','rutas'))->with('rutaU',$request->rutasU);
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al realizar el filtrado con el scope no se como acceder a las rutas asignadas al chofer ya que la ruta a su vez se relaciona con otras dos tabas, ciudades origen y ciudades destino. En un caso anterior en el cual tenia que obtener al chofer de una ruta por su RFC lo realice de la siguiente manera:

```
public function scopeRfc($query, $rfc){
    $query->with('solicitadaPor')->whereHas('solicitadaPor', function($query) use($rfc) {
        $query->where('rfc','LIKE','%' . $rfc . '%');
    });
}
```

¿Como podría obtener los choferes que tengan asignada la ruta obtenida del `select` si los `id` de las rutas son distintos?

Comment: Si pudieras ser mas explícito y claro en tu duda te lo agradecería ya que no es comprendo lo que tratas de obtener

Comment: @Aprendiz Claro, quiero obtener los chóferes con una ruta en especifico pero las rutas que muestro en el select cambian de id ya que estas son creadas por un cliente y en la vista el cliente debe filtrar para obtener a los chóferes que tienen esas rutas en común pero los id de las rutas asignadas a los chóferes son distintos, espero haberme explicado bien, saludos.

Comment: Si tienes dos tablas, una que tiene los choferes con un `id` y otra con las rutas en donde guardas los id de cada chofer, tendrias que relacionar las tablas con `inner join`. Pero los id no deben tener el mismo nombre, me refiero a que la tabla choferes de tener `idc` y la tabla ruta `idr` que contenga una fila llamada `idchofer` asi no tendras problemas para relacionarlar